# What pressure differential is required to generate a mach 2 wind tunnel?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

To research small scale supersonic combustion I considered a simple bullwhip, but I need air moving at mach 2 for up to one second to test a sustained combustion reaction.

The wind tunnel is 2cm diameter and 20cm long.

With the tunnel outlet at STP, what $\Delta$p is needed to move air through this tunnel at Mach-2?

Also is there a way to know if the air will be heated significantly by this acceleration or head loss? The tunnel will be pyrite glass.

Answer (score 1):

For a wind tunnel nozzle, the way to acquire a desired exit Mach number is to compute the quasi one-dimensional relations (also called isentropic relations, see image below). The exit to throat area ratio $A/A^*$ has a functional relation with $\mathcal{M}$, so that $A_e/A^*  = f(\mathcal{M_e})$. So insert $\mathcal{M_e}=2$, then choose a desired throat area, this will determine the exit area required to achieve an exit Mach number of 2. You can also compute all the pressure relations ($\Delta p$ and others) from the equations below which all have functional relations with $\mathcal{M}$.

[image]